# Jetpack Compose pointerInput detectTapGestures Set onLongPress timeout?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, gesture, long-click

To implement a Long Press feature on a button or a composable in general  the way is to use  the Tap Gestures detected in the modifier pointerinput

the code seems pretty straightforward and it works.

```
Box(modifier = modifier.pointerInput(Unit) {

    detectTapGestures(
        onPress = {
            //Do something
        },
        onDoubleTap = {
           
        },
        onLongPress = {
            onLongClick()
        },
        onTap = {

        }
    )
}
```

But what I need is to modify  the timeout in milliseconds  before a longpress event is detected (if the box is pressed for a time of tomeoutMillisec  then a longPress event is fired)

The pointerInput scope  has  the  'val viewConfiguration'  (ViewConfiguration is an Interface)  that contains   the  val 'longPressTimeoutMillis'.
But I cannot  reassign those values (not the longPressTimeoutMillis,  not reassign the class viewConfiguration) because  they are val and not var

```
Box(modifier = modifier.pointerInput(Unit) {

    //this gives an error
    this.viewConfiguration.longPressTimeoutMillis  = 200L
    
    detectTapGestures(
        onPress = {
 
        },
        onDoubleTap = {
            
        },
        onLongPress = {
            onLongClick()
        },
        onTap = {

        }
    )
},
```

Anyone knows  how to do it?

Answer (score 9):

The question is from a month ago but if others need it.
You need to give a new ViewConfiguration in the CompositionLocalProvider that will then wrap your content.

You can put the whole thing in a composable method like below:

```
    @Composable
    fun UpdateViewConfiguration(
        longPressTimeoutMillis: Long? = null,
        doubleTapTimeoutMillis: Long? = null,
        doubleTapMinTimeMillis: Long? = null,
        touchSlop: Float? = null,
        content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
        fun ViewConfiguration.updateViewConfiguration() = object : ViewConfiguration {
            override val longPressTimeoutMillis
        get() = longPressTimeoutMillis ?: this@updateViewConfiguration.longPressTimeoutMillis

            override val doubleTapTimeoutMillis
        get() = doubleTapTimeoutMillis ?: this@updateViewConfiguration.doubleTapTimeoutMillis

            override val doubleTapMinTimeMillis
        get() =
            doubleTapMinTimeMillis ?: this@updateViewConfiguration.doubleTapMinTimeMillis

            override val touchSlop: Float
        get() = touchSlop ?: this@updateViewConfiguration.touchSlop
        }

        CompositionLocalProvider(
            LocalViewConfiguration provides LocalViewConfiguration.current.updateViewConfiguration()
        ) {
            content()
        }
    }
```

and thento modidy the

```
    UpdateViewConfiguration(
        longPressTimeoutMillis = 200L
    ) {
        [... Your content composable ...]
    }
```